# VSTS - Deployment Group release not working: Unable to deploy to the target as the target is offline

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Deployment Groups in VSTS to deploy my application to an on premise test web server.
It has been working fine for a long time, but after having not used it for about 6 weeks I am now getting this error which I would like to fix;
[image]

Comment: Updating the Agent to the latest version can also solve the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your agent is not running or it does not have access to reach VSTS.

Check your agent status on the deployment group configuration.

[image]

Check if the agent is running on your server, searching on Windows Services for VSTS Agent. It will have the name appended to the name of the service. Start it if it is not running and go back to deployment groups to see if it is online. It not, it could be your firewall.

If nothing else works, try to reinstall the agent. It is some configuration issue.

Comment: The agent is Offline. Does this mean it is a Firewall issue? I thought the point was that in using deployment groups we can get round firewalls?

Comment: is the agent windows service running or is it stopped? That is the first thing to check. If it is running, then check the internet connection to be sure your agent is reaching vsts.

Comment: I had a look in windows services and the VSTS agent is up and running. I restarted it anyway and got the same result.

Comment: Stop the Windows Service, open a command prompt and go to path where your agent is installed on the prompt. Then execute the run.cmd. This will run the agent in the console you will see if it can connect your vsts account. If the error message says the agent cannot find or reach the vsts server, then you firewall is blocking it.

Comment: I did that and I got an error message which says "Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A Windows service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Service Administrative tool or the NET START command." Yet the agent is running, it must be installed?

Comment: Just guessing, can the version of the agent be the issue here? I mean, it might make sense to reinstall the agent using the latest dist downloaded from VSTS...

Comment: @arame3333, I would try to reinstall the agent. Just to clarify it for us, how did your installed it the first time?

Comment: I am getting help from Microsoft Support. I will let you know what we find - it is not sorted out yet.

Comment: It would be nice if you share your results later on that. Let me know if there is anything else to help with.

Comment: It was all very confusing, I was getting error messages about certificates and so forth, but eventually the solution appeared to be to reinstall the agent, which is what you suggested.

Comment: I'm glad that is worked. I edited my answer to add my comment. You could accept it.